# derivative of $y=(x^2+x^3)^4$

Tags: derivatives

I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

$$y=(x^2+x^3)^4$$
chain rule it first
$$4(x^2+x^3)^3* \frac d{dx}(x^2+x^3)$$

which should become:
$$4(x^2+x^3)^3(2x+3x^2)$$
factoring out should give me:
$$4*x^2*x(1+x)^3(2+3x)$$

which to me says the answer is: $4x^3(1+x)^3(2+3x)$

but the book says: $4x^7(1+x)^3(2+3x)$

where did I go wrong?

Comment: This is your mistake:$$(x^2+x^3)^3=(x^2(1+x))^3=\color{red}{x^6}(1+x)^3$$

Comment: @DonAntonio It should be only $x$ at the end instead of $x^3$

Comment: Indeed @PandaBear, edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in the factoring out. When you factor $x^2$ out from the $(x^2+x^3)^3$ term, it becomes $(x^2)^3(1+x)^3=x^6(1+x)^3$ instead of $x^2(1+x)^3$